# Typesetting math: an optimisation problem (cost & constraints)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I really struggle to align a system of equation for an optimisation problem. It was all ok at the beginning until I started adding the constraint.

I've got this code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize}\qquad && \parallel A^{\text{ind}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{ind}})\parallel\\
\text{subject to }\qquad && w=b-s+w^0\\
\phantom{\text{subject to }} & l^b &\le b &\le u^b\\
\phantom{\text{subject to }} & l^s &\le s &\le u^s\\
\phantom{\text{subject to }} & l^{\text{bukd}} &\phantom{\le}  t(b+s) &\le u^t\\
\phantom{\text{subject to }} & l^{\text{bukd}} &\le A^{\text{dur}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{buk}}) &\le u^{\text{bukd}}\\
\phantom{\text{subject to }} & l^{\text{curp}} &\le A^{\text{dur}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{cur}}) &\le u^{\text{curp}}\\
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the variable 'b' and 's' are not aligned in the middle. Moreover, the first less-or-equal signs are not aligned as well although they all have a symbol '&' before each of them.

Does anyone can help aligning, in the center, all the constraints of my optimisation problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: The use of `\parallel` for denoting a norm is discouraged. Instead, use `\lVert` and `\rVert`.

Comment: What alignment are you exactly trying to achieve? Is the overall objective to effectively center all of the constraint statements?

Comment: I'm trying to align the first norm, with w=b-s+w, and b, and s etc... but I want a center aligment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can use the following for further improvements (you can remove `\qquad`, avoid `\parallel` etc.) but it will be progressively uglier;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\diagpars}{(}{)}
\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}\diagpars}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\displaystyle \left\| #1 \right\|}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
\text{minimize} &&& \norm{A^{\text{ind}} w \diag{x^{\text{ind}}}}\\
\text{subject to } &&& w=b-s+w^0\\
& l^b             &\le &b                                             &\le &u^b\\
& l^s             &\le &s                                             &\le &u^s\\
& l^{\text{bukd}} &\le &t(b+s)                                        &\le &u^t\\
& l^{\text{bukd}} &\le &A^{\text{dur}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{buk}}) &\le &u^{\text{bukd}}\\
& l^{\text{curp}} &\le &A^{\text{dur}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{cur}}) &\le &u^{\text{curp}}\\
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead reformulate what your constraint is actually meaning for example `b\in[l^b,u^b]` etc.

Comment: i'd suggest using either `\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}` and then `\diag` for that string and similarly for the ones used as superscripts, or `\mathrm` for all of them, since, if this appears in an (italicized) theorem, they will all otherwise be set in italic.  also, as a comment on the question suggested, `\lVert` and `\rVert` are *much* preferable to `\parallel`, which is defined as a relation, hence will have incorrect spacing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There are many things to consider :) I've added a few more options.

Answer (score 11):

The following may be close to what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Minimize\quad} 
\| A^{\text{ind}} w \diag(x^{\text{ind}}) \| 
\]
\[ 
\begin{array}{r @{}c@{} c @{}c@{} l}
\text{subject to:\quad}w&{}={}&\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{b-s+w^0}\\
l^b &\le& b &{}\le{}& u^b\\
l^s &\le& s &\le& u^s\\
l^{\text{bukd}} &\le&  t(b+s) &\le& u^t\\
l^{\text{bukd}}  &\le& A^{\text{dur}} w \diag(x^{\text{buk}}) 
   &\le& u^{\text{bukd}}\\
l^{\text{curp}}  &\le& A^{\text{dur}} w \diag(x^{\text{cur}}) 
   &\le& u^{\text{curp}}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The syntax governing the `array` environment may seem a bit dense at first, so here's a quick guide:

- the two `@{}c@{}` constructs serve to position the equality/inequality symbols; the `@{}` directive suppresses the normal amount of intercolumn whitespace,
- the `r`, `c`, and `l` directives serve to position the remaining material,
- in the first row of the array, the `{}={}` stuff informs LaTeX that the `=` symbol should be treated as a relation operator (by inserting a bit of whitespace on either side); the same goes for the `{}\le{}` in the second row of the array. (Note that it's only necessary to specify the extra `{}` stuff *once* per column.)
- In the first row of the array, the material on the RHS of the equality relation is forced flushleft via a `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{...}` statement. The `@{}` before the "l" is there to suppress LaTeX's default behavior of (re)inserting extra intercolumn whitespace in the amount of `\arraycolsep`.

Finally, I've placed the "minimize" and "subject to" groups into two separate displaymath environments. This inserts a bit more space and, should the need to do so arise, facilitates inserting a page break between the two groups.

Comment: I keep trying to find a reason not to like this because the array syntax is so opaque.  But an array is *the* way to do it and the result is perfect.

Comment: @RyanReich - Thanks. I'll go ahead and provide some explanatory comments to make the syntax hopefully a bit less opaque. :-)

Comment: It's a great explanation, though you already had my vote.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution would simply be left aligning the constraints, by using a single alignment character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize}\qquad & \| A^{\text{ind}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{ind}})\|\\
\text{subject to }\qquad & w=b-s+w^0\\
& l^b \le b \le u^b\\
& l^s \le s \le u^s\\
& l^{\text{bukd}} \phantom{\le}  t(b+s) \le u^t\\
& l^{\text{bukd}} \le A^{\text{dur}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{buk}}) \le u^{\text{bukd}}\\
& l^{\text{curp}} \le A^{\text{dur}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{cur}}) \le u^{\text{curp}}\\
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Would then produce the following:

[image: Output]

Comment: Very clean, quite nicer

Comment: Are the `\phantom{\text{subject to }}` necessary?

Comment: Do replace `\parallel` with either `\|` or `\Vert` to avoid the extra bit of whitespace inserted by the former method.

Comment: @petergrill yes, good point. Updated and replaced `\parallel`

Answer (score 5):

here's another possibility, although whether it's preferable to the one by percusse is a matter of personal taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}
\llap{\text{minimize}\qquad\qquad} & \| A^{\mathrm{ind}} w \diag (x^{\mathrm{ind}})\| \\
\llap{\text{subject to}\qquad\qquad} & w=b-s+w^0
\end{split}\\
\begin{alignedat}{3}
  l^b &\le b &&\le u^b\\
  l^s &\le s &&\le u^s\\
  l^{\mathrm{bukd}} &\phantom{{}\le{}}  t(b+s) &&\le u^t\\
  l^{\mathrm{bukd}} &\le A^{\mathrm{dur}} w \diag(x^{\mathrm{buk}}) &&\le u^{\mathrm{bukd}}\\
  l^{\mathrm{curp}} &\le A^{\mathrm{dur}} w \diag(x^{\mathrm{cur}}) &&\le u^{\mathrm{curp}}
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: I think @Mico wins :) Though I would still write the inqualities as intervals to avoid such problems (or even put them into text as inline math).

Comment: @percusse -- i agree, and not just on time.  mico's result looks nicer than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility, with inequality signs vertically aligned, but keeping the cost and equality constraint to the left:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize}   \quad & \lVert A^{\text{ind}} w \text{ diag}(x^{\text{ind}})\rVert \\
\text{subject to} \quad & w=b-s+w^0 \\
                        & \hspace{-.3em} % this is for correcting a small offset of the array to the right
\begin{array}{lcccl}
    l^b                 & \leq  & b                                           & \leq  & u^b             \\
    l^s                 & \leq  & s                                           & \leq  & u^s             \\
    l^{\text{bukd}}     & \leq  & t(b+s)                                      & \leq  & u^t             \\
    l^{\text{bukd}}     & \leq  & A^{\text{dur}} w \diag (x^{\text{buk}})     & \leq  & u^{\text{bukd}} \\
    l^{\text{curp}}     & \leq  & A^{\text{dur}} w \diag (x^{\text{cur}})     & \leq  & u^{\text{curp}} \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From all your suggestions, it looks like as it is not recommended to use the align editor to write down equation. Matrix and array look much more handy.